# Find a Char in a PHP String

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a site that prints out some stuff from a database. I need it to print on a new line after the '#' char is encountered in the string retrieved from the database. How do I go about making it print on a new line?

Comment: Have you tried printing a new line character?

Comment: So what does JavaScript and html have to do with this?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: The `str_replace()` function should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all `#` characters with a `#` followed by a line break `HTML` tag using the following code: `str_replace("#","#<br/>",$StringFromDB);`

Comment: He didn't say he wants to remove the `#`, he wants the newline *after* it.

Comment: ok it's fixed now then